# How do I get class com.google.common.base.Precondition for Java gDrive api?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to get a Java interface going with Google Drive API by following the quickstart tutorial, but every time I run my program it throws "NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions." This has also happened when I tried implementing the Google CustomSearchEngine API.

I have referenced all API classes with and without sources and javadocs attached. I have also attempted using findJAR dot com in attempt to obtain Preconditions with little success.

Here are the lines of the code I used that the error references. I have also included the the lines which define the variables used within the error lines in comments above the referenced code.

Line 61:

```java
/*
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(clientSecretFilePath);
*/

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Line 88:

```java
/*
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
*/

Credential credential = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
```

Error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:80)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromReader(JsonFactory.java:236)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(GoogleClientSecrets.java:192)
    at drive.GDrive.getCredentials(GDrive.java:61)
    at drive.GDrive.main(GDrive.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

It appears to behave as if a class is missing, but I have referenced all API libraries from Google Drive's API in the build config. I have even tried getting the missing class from findjar dot com with little additional progress.

Comment: I try to include `guava-28.1-jre.jar` in build and run path. But, I will then get a different error message "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Preconditions"

Comment: Hi @Percy could you add your pom.xml file to the post?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Could you list dependencies in your pom.xml/build.gradle ? If you are not using build tool, then list all jars you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove existing dependencies and add dependencies from below links:

[google-api-client-1.23.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.23.0)

[google-oauth-client-jetty-1.23.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty/1.23.0)

[google-api-services-drive-v3-rev110-1.23.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/v3-rev110-1.23.0)

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while implementing [PayU SDK for Android](http://developers.payu.com/en/mobile_sdk.html). 
Solution was to add guava dependencies for **android**, not the **jre**:

```
  implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android")
```

For more information on it, see the [repository](https://github.com/google/guava) or check the [Android guava wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Android), preferably [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained)

I also advise to take a look into [Proguard rules for Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) to exclude all the things you don't use in the project from builds.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small project that followed the quickstart tutorial without any problem.

https://github.com/lssilva/googleDriveApi/

It worked fine for me, I didn't commit the credentials but if you replace with yours, it should work as described in the documentation.

```
git clone https://github.com/lssilva/googleDriveApi.git
gradle run
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted answer does not work for anyone.

Precondition is also available at:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client/google-api-client-repackaged-com-google-common-base

implementation("com.google.api.client:google-api-client-repackaged-com-google-common-base:1.2.3-alpha")
```

It seems to work well for me.